# upload image error using node-formidable

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I was learning "The Node beginner book" and doing the practice in the book, the practice is to present a picture which was uploaded by user. it's an example wrote with `node-formidable`, code as below:

```
var formidable = require('formidable'),
http = require('http'),
util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" '+
    'method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8888);
```

I run it with `node filename.js`, then I open my browser located to http://localhost:8888/upload, comes something as below:

[image]

I enter a name and choose a file, then it comes as below:

[image]

I click the `upload` button, the response as below:

```
received upload:

{ fields: { title: 'Hello Wolrd' },
  files: 
   { upload: 
      File {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        size: 37417,
        path: '/tmp/upload_a306115e1e630a0c548b6d820fe803cb',
        name: 'myfile_icon_file_4.png',
        type: 'image/png',
        hash: null,
        lastModifiedDate: 2016-10-11T03:52:41.052Z,
        _writeStream: [Object] } } }
```

how to get the property `path`? why does a word `File` created there?

Comment: It is an internal representation of the `formidable` library. An instance of `File`. You can access the path via: `files.upload.path`

Comment: I tried, but comes error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`, how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `path` is available on the `File` object, which formidable defines in its code. As your example is written, your `form.parse` function is giving you a map of `File` objects called `files` (go figure). Therefore, if you wanted to get the `path` value to the file you just uploaded, you would do the following (using the key `upload` since that's what your html `input`'s `name` is):

`var pathToFile = files['upload'].path;`

Remember, this is only going to be available server side with the way your example is written, so for you to get the path like this you would put that line of code within your `form.parse` function.

The printout you are giving in your example is from the response, which is what the client is getting. The [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) you are using to format your response is explicitly converting both the `fields` and `files` objects to string representations for debugging/inspection purposes, so that's why you can't access them as a variable on the client side. If you use the line I wrote above or the line notion suggested, it will access `path` as long as it is inside your `form.parse` function where `files` exists within scope.